# Call a method in Spring mvc service cost too much time

Tags: java, spring, resin

My English is not so good. Code first.

```
    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value = "testcall")
    public UnifiedResponse testMethodCall(
            HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) {
        UnifiedResponse unifiedResponse = new UnifiedResponse();
        logger.info("t1:"+System.currentTimeMillis());
        Fun(0,1452,"abd",1);
        logger.info("t2:"+System.currentTimeMillis());
        userSignService.testcall();
        logger.info("t3:"+System.currentTimeMillis());

        return unifiedResponse;
    }


    String  Fun(int i,long l,String s,int ii){
        logger.info("f1:"+System.currentTimeMillis());
        return "";
    }
```

and log output :

```
 t1:1393816077311
 f1:1393816077312
 t2:1393816077312
 f2:1393816077345
 t3:1393816077410
```

`testcall()` is a method in a service, with neither parameter nor return value. just output the timestamp.

Service is implemented like this:

```
@Service
public class UserSignServiceImpl extends BaseServiceImpl implements IUserSignService {
 public void testcall() {
    logger.info("f1:"+System.currentTimeMillis());
 }

}
```

instantiated by annotation

```
@Autowired
IUserSignService userSignService;
```

This only happen on some of the servers. On others t3-t1 is less than 2ms.All servers use same version of JDK and Resin.

Why?

stack trace between caller and method:

```
UserSignServiceImpl.testcall() line: 448    
NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Method, Object, Object[]) line: not available [native method]  
NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Object, Object[]) line: 39  
DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Object, Object[]) line: 25  
Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 597  
AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(Object, Method, Object[]) line: 319 
ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint() line: 183  
ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed() line: 150  
TransactionInterceptor.invoke(MethodInvocation) line: 110   
ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed() line: 172  
ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(MethodInvocation) line: 90   
ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed() line: 172  
JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(Object, Method, Object[]) line: 202   
$Proxy49.testcall() line: not available 
OtherController.testMethodCall(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse) line: 6329
```

Comment: Where did `userSignService` even come from?

Comment: public interface IUserSignService ; implement like :@Service
public class UserSignServiceImpl extends BaseServiceImpl implements IUserSignService

Comment: Fair enough, but I don't see where it's declared or instantiated.  Without that, there's no reasonable way we can answer this question.

Comment: @Autowired
 IUserSignService userSignService;

Comment: Please get a stacktrace from the `testcall()` method and post it here, probably spring does something inbetween that causes the slow.

Comment: I append stacktrace at the end of the question .It seems the framework do lot of things,but I can't change that.

Comment: It works fine on some servers.So I think there might be something wrong about the environment,like java or resin config

Comment: Where is `f2:` in sysout?

Comment: are you sure you have same application version deployed to all servers?

Comment: Maybe the disk of the slow server is slower than on the other ones. Remove all the logging calls (except the last one, which would display the total time), and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: How much time is `much`? 312 - 410 (considering impressions) means less than 100 milliseconds for a call that does IO (log may be written to the disk as well as the console) and God knows what else (those intermediate spring Proxies, AOP and reflection). Is it really affecting your application? Also, have the VM been properly warmed up? (If you just deployed on those servers it may take longer to execute on the first runs).

Comment: Normally, it takes less than 2ms.This is a interface to provide data for mobile client.Usually there are many method will be called during one request, and now the response time is more than 2 seconds.It only takes 70-90ms on other servers.

Comment: IO is not likely the reason, I add the log after feel the response is slower

Answer (score 0):

The reason is interceptor. Once I remove it, t3-t2 down to 1ms.
org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager
All method in package com.xxx.service will trigger this manager.I don't know the internal mechanisms, but I guess may be like this:
    The server process faster has 12M L3 Cache in CPU, the slower one has not.The service methods is called everywhere ,makes it the most frequently used.The faster server might cache it, so process faster.
    I'm not sure.Is there some explanation else?